# pip pyaudio raspberry pi (jessie) install error

Tags: pip, raspberry-pi2, pyaudio

Running Raspbian (Jessie) on Raspberry Pi 2.
Using virtualenv for python. When trying to install pyaudio I get an error.

```
Using:
Python 2.7.9
pip 8.1.1 from /home/kidkic/audio/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Command line when running

```
(cv) kidkic@pi-mirror1:~ $ cd audio/
(cv) kidkic@pi-mirror1:~/audio $ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) kidkic@pi-mirror1:~/audio $ pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.9.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyaudio ... error
  Complete output from command /home/kidkic/audio/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-yDlk2d/pyaudio/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpE1nQfhpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7
  copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7
  ......
```

For full output https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27479515/forums/pyaudioerr.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemed like something was missing with portaudio. To fix it I did this:

```
wget http://www.portaudio.com/archives/pa_stable_v19_20140130.tgz
tar xf pa_stable_v19_20140130.tgz 
cd portaudio/
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo nano ~/.bashrc

    #ADD TO FILE
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/local/lib"
    export LD_RUN_PATH
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/
    export PATH


#REBOOT DEVICE

pip install pyaudio

#HAPPY NOW IT WORKS
```